cannot open phpMyAdmin on IIS
I'm using IIS on windows 10 to set up my website for testing. I have PHP and MySQL working. however, when trying to access the phpMyAdmin login I get this error:
Warning: require_once(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpMyAdmin\libraries/constants.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line 22

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpMyAdmin\libraries/constants.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpMyAdmin\index.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line 22

I've set this up before on Linux and didn't have any issues. Did I miss something in the config file?
edited phpMyAdmin config.sample.inc.php file to recommended settings, error still shows up

Well does that path exist? Presumably not

Since PHP 7.x all reached end of life, PHP on Windows/IIS is no longer supported by Microsoft. So if you have any issue with PHP, you can contact PHP community. https://www.php.net/support.php

fixed it by uninstalling it and reinstalling it with chocolatey. I can now access it on localhost:3000.
